# How to properly run a calculation in the background of an android app?

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask, background-process, reset

I'm trying to run some simple calculation in an App and I want it to always run, even if the App is not visible/active. I've looked up some possibilities and ended up using the ASyncTask. However, when I try to execute it, it's actually not running in the background. It's not running at all to be precise.
So my question is: is the AsyncTask really the best way to do this calculation or should I rather use a Service or something else? And if the ASyncTask is the right way to do it, what am I doing wrong?

Here is the relevant code:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener{

    long startTime = System.nanoTime();


    public class resetSpm extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        if((System.nanoTime() - startTime) > 2000000000) {
            //some simple calculation
        }
        return null;
      }
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        new resetSpm().execute();
    }
}
```

I've also tried to put the execute in the OnCreate with no result.

The if((System.nanoTime() - startTime) > 2000000000) {...} is there instead of a timer because I set the startTime to some other time as well.
This part's task should be to reset a value every 2 seconds without anything happening.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: So I've set up a Service but without any result.
This is the code to that:

```
public class SpmResetService extends Service {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.v("spmService", System.currentTimeMillis() + "spmService has been created.");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startedId) {
        Log.v("spmService", System.currentTimeMillis() + "spmService has been started.");
        if((System.nanoTime() - startTime) > 2000000000) {
            //my calculation
        }
        stopSelf();
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.v("spmService", System.currentTimeMillis() + "spmService has been bound.");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.v("spmService", System.currentTimeMillis() + "spmService has been destroyed.");
    }
}
```

I've then started it in the onCreate like this:

```
Intent spmReset = new Intent(this, SpmResetService.class);
    startService(spmReset);
```

I have also edited the manifest with

```
<service
        android:name="SpmResetService"
        >
    </service>
```

But here it tells me that this Service's name cannot be resolved.

Comment: 2 questions; do you want the calculation to repeat once it's finished for an indeterminate amount of time? Does the effect of the calculation effect the UI in anyway?

Comment: It's supposed to always run ao for an indeterminate amount of time.

Comment: Right now it does affect the UI just so I can see if it does the calculation but in the end it won't need to

Comment: its probably not running because AsyncTasks only run once, and on the first invocation 2 seconds have not yet elapsed since the class invocation and onStart so it fails the if statement. If you want it to repeat when the app is in the background, you will need a `service`. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: I've tried to set one up without any result.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should look into [Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) which are specifically made for this purpose.

You cannot handle UI from the doInBackground, this is possible from the onPostExecute method.

Also can you put a debug message in the doInBackground method so as to see if the task is getting executed or not. Ideally you should use the debugger for this but just for now Log statements should do.

```
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    Log.d("MyApp", "In doInBackground");

    if((System.nanoTime() - startTime) > 2000000000) {
        //some simple calculation
       Log.d("MyApp", "Executing if block");
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Also make sure the condition you are checking is true, which in this case is seems to be false.

Comment: Great going. Let me know if there are any questions.

Comment: I actually do. It's not working. It seems the Service is never even created.

Comment: Could you be more specific, please paste the code if necessary. You can create a new issue and paste the link here.

Comment: I can't post another question at the moment but I did edit this thread.

Comment: The log doesn't show anything related to the Service by the way

Comment: Let's debug this. Is the service tag is inside the application tag in the manifest ?

Comment: Also does the log say anything ?

Comment: Nothing related to the service

Comment: And yes, it is inside the application tag

Comment: Any ideas to what it could be?